# How to correctly apply yt:accessControl in YouTube-API Java

Tags: java, xml, permissions, youtube-api

I have a video on YouTube which I have uploaded which I wish to change yt:accessControls on (particularly comment moderating). I've looked at the YouTube API Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3aaccessControl) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Setting_Access_Controls), but I can't seem to get it updating properly. Here's my code:

```
//Strings declared beforehand: appName, developerId, username, password, and vidId.
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(appName, developerId);
service.setUserCredentials(username, password);

String videoEntryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/" + vidId;
VideoEntry createdEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl), VideoEntry.class);

String originalXMLBlob = createdEntry.getXmlBlob().getBlob();

String atomXml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:fields='yt:accessControl' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='moderated'/></entry>";

GDataRequest request = service.createPatchRequest(new URL(createdEntry.getEditLink().getHref()));
request.getRequestStream().write(atomXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
request.execute();
createdEntry = service.parseResponseData(request, VideoEntry.class);

String newXMLBlob = createdEntry.getXmlBlob().getBlob().substring(49);
//The substring(49) is because after you do a service.parseResponseData... it attaches a timestamp to the xmlBlob. To properly compare whether these are the same in the printlns I substring it.

System.out.println(newXMLBlob.equals(originalXMLBlob));
System.out.println(originalXMLBlob);
System.out.println(newXMLBlob);
createdEntry.update();
createdEntry.update();

newXMLBlob = createdEntry.getXmlBlob().getBlob().substring(49);
System.out.println(newXMLBlob.equals(originalXMLBlob));
System.out.println(originalXMLBlob);
System.out.println(newXMLBlob);
System.out.println("Done");
```

The output is:

```
false
<yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='comment'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='commentVote'/><yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='videoRespond'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='rate'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='embed'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='list'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='autoPlay'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='syndicate'/>
<yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='comment'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='commentVote'/><yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='videoRespond'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='rate'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='embed'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='list'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='autoPlay'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='syndicate'/>
false
<yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='comment'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='commentVote'/><yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='videoRespond'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='rate'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='embed'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='list'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='autoPlay'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='syndicate'/>
<yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='comment'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='commentVote'/><yt:accessControl permission='moderated' action='videoRespond'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='rate'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='embed'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='list'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='autoPlay'/><yt:accessControl permission='allowed' action='syndicate'/>
Done
```

The important thing is that nothing changed from start to finish. You can see I even tried doing `createdEntry.update();` but that doesn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Oh, and one last thing. I would like my atomXml to be able to set access controls to multiple things (video responses, rating, etc.). I'm guessing you just add more `yt:accessControl` tags, but in answering, if you have any tips about that, I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Edit: Removed a space in a url in the xml. This caused a change in output (also updated) which makes more sense, but it's not the desired solution.

Comment: Problem solved, I only have 34 reputation points though so I'll post the answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't make the space problem in the xml originally I wouldn't have had to post this question. Turns out that you can't update the yt:accessControl immediately after uploading the video. So instead I'm saving the Ids ans I upload them and then when they're all finished I'm going to update the yt:accessControl on each of them. Hope this helps later-comers.

Oh, and by the way, I'm pretty sure you CAN submit several yt:accessControls at once. Happy coding!